# How to open link Url from listview inside fragment?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

If I have a listview inside a fragment, it has a custom layout, an array adapter, a fragment class and an array class.
If I want to open a link when clicking a list contained in the listview, how and where do I put the code?

I have tried the following code that I put in the fragment class, but when I try to click on the available list, my application force closes. Is my code wrong?

```
list_fish_easy.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent linkEasy = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(String.valueOf(arrayListeasy)));
            startActivity(linkEasy);

        }
    });
```

What I want is that I can open the link contained in the arraylist like the following

```
public class Fish extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fish_layout, container, false);
    ListView list_fish_easy = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_fish_easy);
   
    final ArrayList<Animal> arrayListeasy= new ArrayList<>();
    arrayListeasy.add(new Animal("Contoh Nama 1", "Easy", "Ominvore", "7.5", "30 C", "http://images.google.com/images?um=1&hl=en&safe=active&nfpr=1&q=cabomba_aquatica"));
    arrayListeasy.add(new Animal("Contoh Nama 2", "Moderate", "Ominvore", "7.5", "30 C", "http://images.google.com/images?um=1&hl=en&safe=active&nfpr=1&q=cabomba_aquatica"));
    arrayListeasy.add(new Animal("Contoh Nama 3", "Difficult", "Ominvore", "7.5", "30 C", "http://images.google.com/images?um=1&hl=en&safe=active&nfpr=1&q=cabomba_aquatica"));

          final AnimalAdapter animalAdaptereasy = new AnimalAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.list_fish, arrayListeasy);
   
    list_fish_easy.setAdapter(animalAdaptereasy);
    
    list_fish_easy.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent linkEasy = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(String.valueOf(arrayListeasy)));

            if(linkEasy.resolveActivity(requireContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(linkEasy);
            }

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

}

I am very new to creating Android programs. Please help

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: @Jayanthvn i have got this error "android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent"

Comment: What you have here 
String.valueOf(arrayListeasy) 
?

Comment: @KamilJeglikowski i have this list, `final ArrayList<Animal> arrayListeasy= new ArrayList<>();
        arrayListeasy.add(new Animal("Discus", "Easy", "Carnivore", "7.5", "30 C", "http://images.google.com/images?um=1&hl=en&safe=active&nfpr=1&q=discus"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to open url from whole arraylist

```
Intent linkEasy = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(String.valueOf(arrayListeasy)));

Uri.parse(String.valueOf(arrayListeasy)
```

You should get exact field with url from you arraylist
It will be something like

```
Uri.parse(String.valueOf(arrayListeasy.get(position).getYourUrlProperty());
```

whole code

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent linkEasy = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(String.valueOf(arrayListeasy.get(position).getYourUrlProperty());

            if(linkEasy.resolveActivity(requireContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(linkEasy);
            }

        }
```

And also you can get rid of String.valueOf( logic

Answer (score 1):

> `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent`

Before staring activities of [Implicit intents](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#ExampleSend), you need to check whether the device has some component that can handle this intent or not (this is typically browsers in your case), otherwise you will get this exception.

To do that you can use [`intent.resolveActivity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#resolveActivity(android.content.pm.PackageManager)).

```
Intent linkEasy = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(String.valueOf(arrayListeasy)));

if(intent.resolveActivity(requireContext().getPackageManager()) != null) { 
    startActivity(linkEasy);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i have browsers in my device, i think the problem is in this code `Uri.parse(String.valueOf(arrayListeasy)`, because, when i change the value to url link "http://images.google.com/images?um=1&hl=en&safe=active&nfpr=1&q=discus", i can open the link, but what i want is i open urls contained in arraylist

Comment: @Azer89 can you provide a sample value of what you are trying to pass in `Uri.parse()`

Comment: yes, I have updated my post, the arraylist contains 6 strings and the url link is on the 6th string

Comment: @Azer89 please check the answer .. he was faster :)